# to increase the inset required to invoke the swipe back gesture on UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

As it is, when you have a navigationController item on your storyboard stack, you, by default have the swipe back gesture. But you have to swipe from the very edge of the screen to invoke it. Is there a way to have it invoked when swiping from somewhere closer to the middle of the screen like the Instagram app for example? thanks. I'm using swift 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to implement a custom interactive transition.

You can take a look at this example:

http://www.thinkandbuild.it/interactive-transitions/

Apple docs:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CustomizingtheTransitionAnimations.html

Once you get the concept, you will be able to implement what you are asking about.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @fiks. But I'm only a swift beginner. Next to 0 knowledge of objc and i've always found the apple documentation too cryptic for the most part. Is there another way (easier way) to do it? An extension to the class or a simpler work around? I'll be studying up on the custom transition from the link you sent me just in case there's no other way. Again, thank you!!!

Comment: I don't know if there is a quick workaround. I've never had this problem :)
But for sure you will be able to achieve it with a custom transition.